# PHP - Redirect based on OS optimization

Tags: php, optimization

I'm new to PHP and I would like to redirect the visitors of my website based on their operating system. 
Below is my solution. Is there anything that needs to be optimized?

```
<?php
    // MOBILE
    $android = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Android");
    $blackberry = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"BB10");
    $ios = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iOS");
    // DESKTOP
    $windows = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Windows");
    $mac = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Mac");

    // REDIRECTS 
    // MOBILE
    if ($android == true) 
    { 
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/android');
    } 
    else if ($blackberry == true) 
    { 
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/blackberry');
    }
    else if ($ios == true) 
    { 
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/ios');
    }
    // DESKTOP
    else if ($windows == true) 
    { 
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/windows');
    }
    else if ($mac == true) 
    { 
    header('Location: http://www.example.com/mac');
    }
    ?>
```

Thanks. Patrick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before anything, I'll let you search on the web why this might not be such a good idea and I'll just focus on the code.

- You probably should retrieve `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` and store it in a variable in order to avoid repeated code. Also, you might want to check if the variable is set properly before accessing it to avoid warnings/errors.
- You can rewrite `if ($variable == true)` as `if ($variable)`
- You could avoid the boilerplate and repeated code if you were storing the interesting parts of your logic in an array and write the common parts only once :

```
    $ua = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] : '';
    $redir = array(
        "Android" => 'android',
        "BB10"    => 'blackberry',
        "iOS"     => 'ios',
        "Windows" => 'windows',
        "Mac"     => 'mac'
    );
    if (isset($redir[$ua]))
    {
        header('Location: http://www.example.com/' . $redir[$ua]);
    }
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: I agree with Josay, this is not a good idea. You might want to look into responsive webdesign.